# Osmdroid. How to use two online tile source base the same time in mapview

Tags: dictionary, osmdroid

Sorry for my bad English. I have question. Is it possible to use two or more online source base the same time in the mapview? For example, i have two online source base, one of this map tiles, and the other one displays traffic jam in the roads. Both tiles are 256x256 px jpg format. I want to display traffic jam tiles above map tiles. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Create a new `TilesOverlay` for your traffic jam tiles and add it to the list of overlays of your map.

Take a look at [SampleWithTilesOverlayAndCustomTileSource.java](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/samples/SampleWithTilesOverlayAndCustomTileSource.java#54) in the OpenStreetMapViewer samples:

```java
final MapView osmv = new MapView(this, 256);

// …

// Add tiles layer with custom tile source
final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = 
        new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
final ITileSource tileSource =
        new XYTileSource("FietsRegionaal", null, 3, 18, 256, ".png",
        new String [] {"http://overlay.openstreetmap.nl/openfietskaart-rcn/"});
tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider,
        this.getBaseContext());
tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

osmv.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno Parmentier! :)